# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_header_image() (previously declared in

Tags: fatal-error

to use that code   `<img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_header_image() ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'title' ) ) ); ?>" />` , i created a functions.php like that

```
 <?php 

function get_header_image() { 
    $url = get_theme_mod( 'header_image', get_theme_support( 'custom-header', 'default-image' ) ); 

    if ( 'remove-header' == $url ) { 
        return false; 
    } 

    if ( is_random_header_image() ) { 
        $url = get_random_header_image(); 
    } 
} 
    ?>
```

but it shows error :

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_header_image() (previously declared in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\wordpress\wp-includes\theme.php:1058) in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\html5blank-stable1\html5blank-stable\functions.php on line 13
```

so how can i solve it?

Comment: that means function with this name `get_header_image` is already declared in this file `\wp-includes\theme.php`  change your function name to something eles like `get_header_image_custom` in `functions.php` file

Comment: @ParthaviPatel in fact i try to enable header image option of theme so what must i do ?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear in this case.

You can’t have two functions with the same name.

WordPress already has function called [`get_header_image`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header_image), so you can’t call your custom function with this name.

That’s why it’s a good idea to add prefixes to functions you declare in your theme. So instead `get_header_image` you call your custom function `MYTHEME_get_header_image` (of course replace `MYTHEME` with name of your theme).

Comment: in fact i try to enable header image option of theme so what must i do ?